# Is it possible the get the facebook "like" button code with the counter not the code where it shows your face when you vote in HTML 4

Tags: html, facebook-like

Is it possible the get the facebook "like" button code with the counter code and not the code where it shows your face when you vote in HTML 4

Answer (score 1):

yeah that should be possible:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

on this site you can uncheck the box "show faces"

*edit*:

ohhh thats HTML5 ... 
HTML4 is compulsory?